# How can I view string content being written by XMLWriter to a Stream/MemoryStream?

Tags: c#, xml, debugging, xmlwriter

How can I view the content I write with `XMLWriter` object to a `MemoryStream` object?
Note that the `MemoryStream`object isn't a member field of the class and I don't have access to it in the relevant method in which I write to it with `XMLWriter`.

I thought I will be able to look at the `MemoryStream` by the `XMLWriter` object itself, which is linked to the `MemoryStream` it writes to, but It seems that who wrote `XMLWriter` didn't think about that option.   :\

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you would like to get string value from your MemoryStream object? 
Try this:

```
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    var sr = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
    var myStr = sr.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(myStr);
```

Comment: I need to view the content in visual studio while debugging, it's weird I need to write code to view what I'm doing.
I will try this now and tell you if it's working.

Comment: OK working but any idea why can't I see the content as I see int value in the debug for example without writing additional code?

Comment: I think you can't view content of any stream in DEBUG because it is too complex type, but you can simply modify above code to one line expression and add it to your watch window and you will see content always after your memory stream variable will be ready